# IntelliJ IDEA auto-completion for collection type declaration with generics

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to figure out how it would be more efficient to type a declaration of a collection type with a generic.

Typing:

```
List<
```

Automatically expands to:

```
List<|>
```

(cursor position is marked with "|")

Typing

```
List<St|>
```

using the autocomplete it gets to

```
List<String|>
```

notice the cursor position

Now the question: how could it be possible to get to the following state without using the arrow keys:

```
List<String> |
```

Ideally, id like to use statement autocompletion for this, but it rather jumps to the new line which is not desired in this situation.

Comment: *end* then *space* works for me... or *f2* then *space*

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have _end_. F2+space would be equal to arrow+arrow

Comment: Anton, you want to specify your problem more rigorously, for example, hitting cmd+enter (finish current statement) and repeatedly hitting backspace to delete semicolon works for me. And it doesn't use arrow keys.

Comment: @OlegŠelajev cmd+space doesn't work for me in this scenario

Comment: For short autocompletions like this I find it faster just to type it. If I type `List<Str` it's much faster just typing `ing> ` than having to pick the correct alternative in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make a `Live Template` for yourself?

For example, go to *Live Templates*, add a new template under *other*, give it an abbreviation `list`, a description as you like, and enter the template text:

```
List<$TYPE$> $VAR$ = new $END$
```

Where it says *No applicable contexts*, define: `Java` -> `Statement`

Now click `Edit variables` and bind as follows

```
TYPE -> expectedType()
VAR -> suggestVariableName()
```

Et voila. The keypresses are now: list <kbd>tab</kbd> St <kbd>enter</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> (varname) <kbd>enter</kbd>

result, with cursor:

```
List<String> myvar = new |
```

And from here you can hit ctrl-shift-space to autocomplete like so:

```
List<String> myvar = new ArrayList<>(|);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No worries, Anton :) btw are you happy to accept this answer?